# self relations in hibernate entity with attributes on relation

Tags: java, hibernate

I have a class A.
each A like a1 is similar to some other A like a2 with similarity s1_2
so I designed a class like this:

```
class A{
    // some properties + id


    Map<A,double> semilars;

}
```

how can i put hibernate annotations on semilars property to build tables like this:

```
|       table A       |
-----------------------
|id| other properties |
```

and

```
|  similarity   table    |
--------------------------
| id1 | id2 | similarity |
```

Answer (score -1):

I found it !!!

simply an @ElementCollection solves the issue!
happy codding.